# Tic Tac Toe game in Python wins as long as line is filled

Tags: python-3.6

For the finals of our high school we were tasked to make a Tic Tac Toe games using basic Python codes. The problem I have with mine is that as long as on line gets filled up, it instantly wins for the player that fills it up regardless of matching O's and X's. I need help to see the problem with my win conditions. Excuse my inefficiency with coding, this is the first time they've taught us Python. Thank you!

https://repl.it/repls/ConsiderateShimmeringBot

Comment: Replace your "and"'s with "==" in your check. "if Aone and Btwo and Cthree == "O":" to "if Aone == Btwo == Cthree == "O":"

Answer (score 1):

To test if all three values equal `"O"`, instead of:

```
if Aone and Btwo and Cthree == "O":
```

You should do:

```
if Aone == Btwo == Cthree == "O":
```

Otherwise you'd be testing if the first two values are not False, and if the third value equals to `"O"`.

Fix this for all of the 16 `if` statements, and your code would work.